# <Arduino> Serial monitor auto-inputs 0 after a loop iteration

Tags: arduino, integer, arduino-uno, serial-monitor

I've been learning how to use the Arduino for 3 days following YT tutorials. I'm currently learning about Input-Output with the serial monitor.

After running the loop once, the serial monitor automatically inputs a 0 and is registered as an input then goes back to accepting user input.

Screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Below is the code:

```cpp
//inputs
int blinks;
String question = "How many times would you like the LED to blink? ";

//LED
int LEDPin = 8;

//while loop
int i = 1;

//delay
int delayTime = 500;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.print(question);

  //this waits for an input <while serial is empty>
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  };

  //this reads the input
  blinks = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(blinks);

  //output
  while (i <= blinks) {
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
    Serial.println(i);
    i++;
  };

  i = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Serial Port might be reading the null terminator ('\0') or some *garbage* is left in the input buffer.

Use `Serial.flush()` after your while loop and see if that solves your problem.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I would suggest using `SerialEvent()` (read [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent)) instead of checking for the serial input in your main loop. This approach is more reliable as it is based on interrupts.

Keep on learning!

Comment: i'll try it out. will be back for an update hahahha

Answer (score 1):

New to this. Struggled for 4 hours with this issue.

At the bottom of the serial monitor there is a check box. Select it to "No new line" instead of "New line" and the problem is solved.

If you type in eg 80. It keeps the 80 and does not reset it to 0.

Yeah

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you.